# Missing aws-exports.js always when building AWS Amplify React app with Amplify integrations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

my React app uses GraphQL API, Storage, Auth, Functions, Hosting - all the fun stuff - so i must have an `aws-exports.js` file available. Amplify React Front end with Amplify Backend resources.

Repo basically setup as:

```
package.json
src/
   - aws-exports.js
   - app.js
   - ...etc
```

and doing an `ls` in each dir showed on builds that there was no `aws-exports.js` file generated.

With many different configs, i am met with:

```
[INFO]: # Executing command: yarn run build
[INFO]: yarn run v1.16.0
[INFO]: $ react-scripts build
[INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
[INFO]: Failed to compile.
[INFO]: ./src/App.js
                                 Cannot find file './aws-exports' in './src'.
2020-04-30T00:52:34.883Z [WARNING]: error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This is so when i have a checked in `amplify.yml` and also configuring the `.yml` in the web console.

I've tried `amplify push;` but as expected met with

```
An error occured during the push operation: Current environment cannot be determined
Use 'amplify init' in the root of your app directory to initialize your project with Amplify
```

Also trying: `amplify pull;` or `Executing command: amplify pull --appId abc123abc123 --envName dev`

```
 # Starting phase: preBuild
# Executing command: amplify pull
For more information on AWS Profiles, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html
? Do you want to use an AWS profile? (Y/n)
.[43D.[43C
```

Which just hangs and expects input. I dont think manually putting in creds like this is as all the way to go about this.

It seems as though amplify should handle this generation of `aws-exports.js` itself considering all the backend integrations. When `ls` different. There are a number of questions around on this that are quite current but with no real answer. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to simply generate aws-exports.js via script before the "npm run build" step.

You simply store aws-exports.js contents in an environment variable called "secretfile", and then use it inside amplify.yml like this

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - echo $secretfile > ./src/aws-exports.js
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Reasons:

1. Committing aws-exports.js to the repo is of course a big no since it contains API keys and other secrets.
2. I did not want to kick off a backend build each time either. Building the backend is counter productive since it creates a new stack for backend for each build, which costs more money, slows things further, plus its error prone.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. For anyone finding this, make sure your environmental variable does not begin with 'aws'.

Comment: just FYI - there is nothing sensitive in aws-exports.js.

Comment: @Exponent could you elaborate? Wouldn't `aws_cognito_identity_pool_id` be considered sensitive?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who lands here, the Amplify console just released a way so that you can autogenerate the aws-exports file at build time without enabling fullstack CI/CD and checking it into your git repo: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-config-autogeneration.html

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution for me. Clean and no additional steps.

Answer (score 4):

Backend resources need `amplifyPush` run to generate the expected `aws-exports.js` file. A normal react+amplify backend project will need a build script looking like:

```
version: 0.1
env:
  variables:
      key: value
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - "**/*"
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

The `amplifyPush` script is a part of the [amplify-console repo](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console), specifically the .sh script is found https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/blob/master/scripts/amplifyPush.sh

See here for more info on other things to run in your build script.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#frontend-with-backend

Answer (score 2):

After using "amplify init" the system asked where to put the files, and specified src as the folder to put it into, and low and behold that's where it placed my aws-export.js. So look around in your folders since it may be placed in another folder and not in the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might be running into the `Cannot find file './aws-exports' in './src'.` error while building the frontend, none of the suggestions I could find (here or elsewhere) led me to an answer.

As stated in the Amplify docs, the `aws-exports.js` file is generated after a successful build of the backend. My Amplify backend appeared as if it was building successfully so it should have been generating the `aws-exports.js` (but it was not).

I closely reviewed my build config in Amplify (Amplify > App Settings > Build settings) and my `backend` settings appeared to match other examples I had seen. Here is how it is configured:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

The `amplifyPush --simple` command is important as it instructs Amplify to build the backend. I then started to review other parts of the backend with the assumption that it appeared like it was building successfully but might be failing. I was led to this because there was not a ton of output when viewing the "backend" phase of the deploy (see below):

```
                                 # Starting phase: build
2022-01-10T13:54:13.394Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
```

This seemed suspiciously devoid of more output. I focused on my schema, in particular, a custom function that I had added and connected to a mutation, which looked like the following:

```
type Mutation {
  generateToken(identity: String!): GenerateTokenResponse
    @function(name: "twilio-${env}")
}

type GenerateTokenResponse {
  token: String
  identity: String
}
```

After removing, I ran an `amplify push --allow-destructive-graphql-schema-updates` which succeeded (`--allow-destructive-graphql-schema-updates` is required because Amplify thinks some data/tables might be deleted in modifying the schema). The backend deployed successfully.

I then did a full deploy of the frontend and backend which ended up successfully deploy. To compare, I checked on the output of the "backend" build phase and found some more output this time:

```
                                 # Starting phase: build
[INFO]: [0mAmplify AppID found: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Amplify App name is: myApp[0m
[INFO]: [0mBackend environment dev found in Amplify Console app: myApp[0m
WARNING]: - Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.
[WARNING]: - Building resource auth/userPoolGroups
[WARNING]: - Building resource auth/myAppAuth
[WARNING]: - Building resource api/myAppApi
[WARNING]: ✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.
[INFO]: 
[INFO]: # Completed phase: build
```

I have not determined what was wrong with these lines from `schema.graphql` but I must have configured something incorrectly. Admittedly, I am not sure if I finished writing that custom function so perhaps that is why. However, no errors were generated that led me to this discovery quickly.

*Note: Amplify app w/React frontend deployed using Amplify CI/CD, hosted on Cloudfront+S3 (via Amplify)*

Answer (score 0):

`$amplify init` creates aws-exports.js, which locates in the place you put "Distribution Directory Path" within the init command. This is an example in next.js.

```
$ amplify init
Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory
? Enter a name for the project sampleapp
? Initialize the project with the above configuration? No
? Enter a name for the environment dev
? Choose your default editor: Visual Studio Code
? Choose the type of app that you're building javascript
Please tell us about your project
? What javascript framework are you using react
? Source Directory Path:  src
? Distribution Directory Path: .next  // <- here!!
? Build Command:  npm run-script build
? Start Command: npm run-script start
Using default provider  awscloudformation
? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the people building in Vue (specifically Vue3 Quasar):

```
import { boot } from "quasar/wrappers";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "../aws-exports";

export default boot(({ app }) => {
    Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
    app.use(Amplify);
});
```

Comment: Can i ask about how you set up your amplify.js as well? i have some issues with it. thanks.

Comment: I did not touch the amplify.js file(s). They were auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

I basically ignore the aws-amplify gererated file list into the `.gitigore` and I removed `aws-exports.js` from `.gitignore`, then commit it by doing this:

1. `git rm -r --cached .`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "Added aws-exports.js file"`
4. `git push`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my React/GraphQL/Amplify stack as well.

Disabling full-stack continuous deployments (CI/CD) on my backend hosting page is what fixed it for me, ie. allowed AWS to auto-generate my AWS config files including aws-exports.js.

[Disable_CICD_Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuufa.png)

AWS gives a bit of an explanation here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-config-autogeneration.html

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add the [backend config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#frontend-with-backend) to my amplify.yml, e.g. for a nextjs monorepo:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: packages/web-client
    backend:
      phases:
        build:
          commands:
            - amplifyPush --simple
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: packages/web-client/.next
        files:
          - "**/*"
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
      buildPath: /
```

I was also using a custom Node 18 image, and needed to install the Amplify CLI within that image (there was an unreported error on backend step without doing this). E.g. this was my Dockerfile for this image:

```
FROM node:18-bookworm
RUN npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

As I am on a ARM based Mac, I also needed to make sure to use `--platform linux/x86-64` when building this custom build image, as Amplify currently doesn't support ARM based images. I Then selected this image to use for builds in the Amplify console.