# Amplify missing aws-exports.js even after running amplifyPush --simple

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

There is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514515/missing-aws-exports-js-always-when-building-aws-amplify-react-app-with-amplify-i) for solving the problem with aws-exports.js.

The first answer with "echo $export" solves it in sort of a workaround way, but I asking this question so that people can have access to the real solution and understand what is happing. I want to believe that AWS developers wouldn't allow such an important feature of amplify to require such action.

This is the root.amplify.yml

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - amplifyPush --simple
        - echo $PWD
        - ls
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - echo $PWD
        - ls
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

It runs the `amplifyPush` command, but with ls we can see that it simply doesn't create `aws-exports.js`. What is happening here? Why it doesn't create?

Comment: It doesn't look like `aws-exports.js` is preserved from the `backend` step as an artifact. Does it need to be listed under `backend`'s `artifacts`?